# Animate div to full screen size from current position on click, click again to animate back to original size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to emulate this general effect... http://www.wolfks.com/about/brand-promises#

So far I have this... [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqjcs66x/)

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.people-container').click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('close-animate') || !$(this).hasClass('screen-animate')) {
        $(this).removeClass('close-animate').addClass('screen-animate');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('screen-animate').addClass('close-animate');
      }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.people-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

.people-container {
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.screen-animate {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  animation: fill-animate 0.5s forwards;
}

.close-animate {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  animation: close-animate 0.5s;
}

/** Fill screen animation **/
@keyframes fill-animate
{ 
    50% { 
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        height: 50%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}

/** Close screen animation **/
@keyframes close-animate
{ 
    50% { 
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="people-container" style="background-color: red;">

  <div class="people-title">
    <h1>Carpenter</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="close-btn">&#10006;</div>

</div>
```

I'm having trouble getting the div to smoothly scale up to full screen. I dont need it to be exactly like the example... basically just looking for the full screen animation and closing animation from and to the div's original position on the page.

Any help?

Comment: So you want to implement what they've done, have you actually looked at what they've done? From all I'm seeing, it's all via CSS. View source on their page. Very neat effects, but it seems to be all right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripped down version following the example website's approach that you linked. It uses CSS `transition` to handle the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.shutter').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('close-animate') || !$(this).hasClass('shutterExpanded')) {
      $(this).removeClass('close-animate').addClass('shutterExpanded');
      $('.wrapper').addClass('shutterOpen');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('shutterExpanded').addClass('close-animate');
      $('.wrapper').removeClass('shutterOpen');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.shutter {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background: #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 1px solid #323232;
  transition: all .75s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.shutterOpen .shutter {
  height: 0;
}

.shutter.shutterExpanded {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="shutter">
    <h2 class="shutterTitle">Roofer</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="shutter">
    <h2 class="shutterTitle">Contractor</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="shutter">
    <h2 class="shutterTitle">Tiler</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="shutter">
    <h2 class="shutterTitle">Electrician</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transition` to animate the height of the elements, you don't need to use `position`

The idea is to set the clicked element's height to full screen size (`100vh`) and the other elements to `0`.

**See snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.people-container').click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass('screen-animate')) {
      $('.people-container').removeClass('close-animate');
      $(this).removeClass('screen-animate');
    } else {
      $('.people-container').addClass('close-animate');
      $(this).addClass('screen-animate');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.people-title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.people-container {
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.close-animate {
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.screen-animate {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.close-btn {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="people-container" style="background-color: red;">

  <div class="people-title">
    <h1>Carpenter</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="close-btn">&#10006;</div>

</div>

<div class="people-container">

  <div class="people-title">
    <h1>Laborer</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="close-btn">&#10006;</div>

</div>

<div class="people-container" style="background-color: blue;">

  <div class="people-title">
    <h1>Roofer</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="close-btn">&#10006;</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!! close is similary

```
.screen-animate {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  animation: fill-animate 1.5s forwards;
}
/** Fill screen animation **/
@keyframes fill-animate
{ 
    0% { 
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```